# Android Capture pic without opening any activity?

Tags: android, camera

i want to capture a picture periodically for every minute. without user interaction.something like capture the image in service. any help will be appreciated. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Root access is a limitation?

Comment: if you are using whatsapp it will open one activity for camera, from that activity it will capture pic, without root access.

Comment: Oh, my mistake! I thought you were meaning Screen capture!

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. How would the `Service` be started without user interaction?

Comment: At startup! Service could be started by a Broadcast Receiver that receives the BOOT_COMPLETED message

Comment: @Squonk Ok, this question has no sense at all.

Answer (score -1):

This is just suggestion.

Use alarm manager, Which is help you access the camera in every minute.

Comment: am asking about take pic without opening any activity, not about alarm manager

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can have a Service that launchs at startup. That service will be part of an Application that has permission to use the camera.

Inside that service you can have something like this:

```
private class threadPhoto extends Thread {

    @Override
    public synchronized void start() {
        super.start();
    }

    public void force() {
        this.force = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        while (true) {

            if (force) {

                try {
                    //Code for taking the photo
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("", "Error");
                }

                force = false;
            }

            try {
                sleep(TIME_INTERVAL_IN_MILLIS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the Service onCreate you should create the threadPhoto object, and periodically call the force() method that it has.

For learn to take photos in Android you should [read this article on Android Developers.](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/camera/index.html)

Comment: i dont need all these stuff i want the code for capture the image. without activity.

Comment: Look at the link I provided you at the end. Do all that stuff that they say in the service.